# Turning off "Language Service Disabled" error message in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, error-messaging

We are getting the following "Error" message in our MVC web application in Visual studio 2017 Enterprise.

> The language service is disabled for project 'C:\Work\Blackhawk
>   Platform\Platform-DEV-Branch\BlackhawkViewer\BlackhawkViewer.csproj'
>   because it included a large number of .js files. Consider excluding
>   files using the 'exclude' section of a 'tsconfig.json' file.

I have tried turning off the Language service in the options but this does not turn the message off:

[image]

This is a rather large web application.  Is there a way to turn this message off without disabling any files in the tsconfig.json file as it suggests?

Comment: Some JavaScript files were excluded from your project .csproj file.

Comment: @iman.Bahrampour No that is not the case here.  This was a VS bug which was fixed.

Comment: As the error shows: `because it included a large number of .js files` in your BlackhawkViewer.csproj file.

A number of .js files included in your project, while they are deleted from your solution.

Comment: It may look irrelevant but In my case I just didn't have enough disk space

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To solve this issue do the following:

- Create file in root directory of your project and call it `tsconfig.json`
- Add this:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true, 
    "noEmit": true, 
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "scripts"
  ],
  "exclude": [

  ],
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true 
  }
}
```

Please have a look at the below two links for tsconfig.json explanation, because you may still need to change it according to your setup. This is the only way that worked for me. I hope that will help.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/8148/javascript-intellisense-not-working.html

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: this solution didn't work for me, i have lots of javascript files and even excluding one of the folders with lots of js files did not work for me, using the tsconfig.json

Comment: I also have a lot of javascript files and it worked, try to clean the solution, rebuild and restart visual studio might help.

Comment: This is the right answer, and a solid one. Thanks for providing the links too.

Comment: I added the above file and now get the error: The config file 'project/tsconfig.json' found doesn't contain any source files.

Comment: This solution does not work. See prior comment by Allan.

Comment: @AllanNielsen it's because you have to list the scripts you want to include, or more simply just do a pattern to capture all the scripts. In my solution, including `wwwroot/**/*.js` captures everything. [See this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Answer (score 22):

This helped me. You can have a try.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript -> Language Service -> General

and uncheck the box: "Enable the new JavaScript language service.

Comment: yes that's the way but at the time I asked the question VS2017 had a bug where it did not honor that setting. It has since been fixed.

Comment: I also had to restart Visual Studio

Comment: @loan.burger This bug still occurs for me.

Comment: for me also. Everytime I update VS2017 to a newer version, bug appears again.

Comment: I also had to reinstall visual studio

Comment: In visual Studio 2013 that command does not exist; but this worked for me: 
Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript - and under Statement Completion, deselect the two checkboxes for: Auto-list members and Parameter information.

Answer (score 9):

I have found a solution for this problem.

I reset my userData using:

> devenv.exe /resetuserdata

Since doing this the JavaScript settings seem to have persisted and I no longer get the  language service error above.

**TAKE NOTE: This will reset all your user data and customisations.**

Comment: I've found that `git clean -fxd` also seems to fix the issue.

Comment: This worked for me. Adding the tsconfig did not , especially if you do not add include, it will complain there is nothing to build

Comment: Sorry I have to take back my comment. Message just re appeared again :(

Comment: I have not had this issue since 3 updates ago.  Make sure your running thevlatest version of vs2017 bu running the visual studio installer and pressing updates if the update button appears.

Comment: where exactly am I supposed to type this?

Comment: @bibek when launching the .exe file.  Best to use the windows command prompt in administrator mode.

Answer (score 2):

In My case I just disable TypeScript support on Visual Studio:

Tools > Extensions and Updates > TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio > Disable

After that, just restart Visual Studio, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after migrating Ionic 1 project from VS2015 to VS2017, first  I executed git clean -fxd as sugested above and added this content into tsconfig.json in my ionic project.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "www",
    "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This adds nothing that isn't covered in Moustafa's answer

Comment: I used the solution implemented by Moustafa and it didn`t work for me. He didn't set up the exclude modules.

Answer (score 1):

**I solved this problem with following solution:**

When you have a JavaScript file that is included in the project.csproj file but isn't in the project folder, this error occurred.

For example I have a .csproj file like below:

```
 <ItemGroup>
     <Content Include="Scripts\Test.js" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

The Test.js is included in the .csproj file, but it isn't in the Scripts folder:

Delete the `<Content Include="Scripts\Test.js" />` line from the .csproj file and rebuild your project

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me:

1. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>.
2. Open command prompt as admin in current folder
3. Ran devenv /Setup
4. Ran devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

Answer (score 1):

For me is helping the next solution. I've create a tsconfig.json file in root of the my project with  "disableSizeLimit": "true" option.

So, my tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "disableSizeLimit": "true"
},
"exclude": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If none of suggested methods worked, try:

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

and then

Install the latest version of ***TypeScript for Visual Studio*** on [Get TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links).