# Visual Studio 2017 JavaScript Language Service has been disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2017

While editing JavaScript source files in Visaul Studio 2017, the following error keeps occuring:

```
The JavaScript language service has been disabled for the following project(s): ...
```

Even if I disable the JavaScript language service entirely, the error keeps occuring. Why is this happening and how do I stop this error message from displaying all the time? Can I disable the JavaScript language service entirely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off "Language Service Disabled" error message in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990428/turning-off-language-service-disabled-error-message-in-vs2017)

Comment: Try this: [Turning off “Language Service Disabled” error message in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990428/turning-off-language-service-disabled-error-message-in-vs2017/57396574#57396574).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem was simply to use a tsconfig.json file, even though there were only JavaScript files in my solution. 
I've just used the following tsconfig.json file in the root of the project:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "amd",
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "lib",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

open 'developer command line tool for visual studio'. run :
devenv.exe /resetuserdata