# The JavaScript language service has been disabled for the following project(s): Click to find out more

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, typescript, tsconfig

I get the following error in my solution:

> Error     The JavaScript language service has been disabled for the
>   following project(s): . Click to find out more.

The web project previously had a `tsconfig` file but this has since been moved to another project. I do not want to create a `tsconfig.json` just to get rid of the error and I don't want to reset all my userdata using:

```
devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

Is there anything I have missed?

[Turning off "Language Service Disabled" error message in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990428/turning-off-language-service-disabled-error-message-in-vs2017)

Comment: Can you please add what you have already tried?

Comment: @pathurs I have looked for solutions but not found anything good. I do not wan't to turn off add a tsconfig file that won't be used and reset my userdata. This seems to be the solutions people have used.

Comment: There exists a limit of 20MB JS files... in this case there seems to be a [solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/130929/the-javascript-language-service-has-been-disabled.html)

Comment: @OlafW There is only on bundled file in the project, 5 MB in development.

Comment: Try this: [Turning off “Language Service Disabled” error message in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990428/turning-off-language-service-disabled-error-message-in-vs2017/57396574#57396574).